# Java : Help need to typecast a String value into a char

Tags: java

Hi all i need to typecast a String value into a char .
Please help me , i am not sure how to do this 
This is my code

At First i have a Enum class as shown

```
public enum RemoteType {
    @XmlEnumValue("Call")
    Call("Call"),
    @XmlEnumValue("Put")
    Put("Put");

    private final String value;

    RemoteType(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static RemoteType fromValue(String v) {
        for (RemoteType c: RemoteType.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

**This Enum ( RemoteType) is present inside a DTO (FOrmBean ) as shown**

```
public class Subform implements Serializable
{
private RemoteType        remoteType;

  public RemoteType getRemoteType()
   {
      return remoteType;
   }

   public void setRemoteType(RemoteType remoteType)
   {
      this.remoteType = remoteType;
   }
}
```

I have another class called as MyObject as shown

```
class MyObject
{
public char side; 
}
```

For this MyObject side property which is a char  i want to assign this remoteType property of FormBean  by calling Getter Method on it.

Now I am setting data inside the DTO Form Object as shown

```
Subform subform = new Subform();

subform.setRemoteType(RemoteType.Put);
```

After setting the data (IN JSP )  that , Now i am  tying to extract it (IN Controller) and   assign String to char as shown .

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.side = Subform.getRemoteType().value(); // How can we assin (Here i am getting errror
```

saying cant assign string to char)

please help me

( The code is of jar files , so we cant change the Data types )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast an entire `String` to a `char`, but if your `String` only has a single character in it, then you can simply do:

```
char theChar = myString.charAt(0);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to decide on how you can convert that `String` into a `char` - maybe you'll just grab the first/last character in the `String`, or maybe you'll perform some algorithm that "sums up" the characters into a single character.
Either way, there's no general way for you to turn a `String` into a `char` as a `String` is just a collection of `char`s.